# count array in plist, create button with title from array items?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist

first,i need to count the items from array.

```
<dict>
    <key>New item</key>
    <array>
        <string>apple</string>
        <string>orange</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

second,load the items into tableview.example,table cell 1 with apple,table cell 2 with orange.
third,create buttons in table cell by count items from array.
fourth,set buttons title with items value.example,button"apple" and button"orange".

where should i start from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with creating a retained property that will be your UITableView's data source.

in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *dataSource; //use retain instead of strong if not using ARC
```

Next extract the array from dictionary into your data source

```
self.dataSource = [dict objectForKey:@"New item"]; //only if it's guaranteed that the dictionary contains that array
```

Next implement your table view's data source protocol with two methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableViewNumberOfRowsInSection:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return dataSource.count; // create cells by count of array
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath {
  static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"fruit";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]; // add autorelease if not using ARC
    //add your UIButton here, give it tag
    UIButton *button = ...;//alloc the button and give it proper frame and add it as cell's subview
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    button.tag = 5;
  }
  //extract the button and give it title
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
  button.title = [dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
}
```

So you must learn about delegation and what protocols are. Read the [UITableView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) for more information.